# Optimised way to display batch job status on Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, batch

In my Visualforce page, the user can schedule a job and after monitor the status of the job whether it is in progress or completed.

Right now, I am querying `AsyncApexJob` table periodically to know job status.

When I google it, few people are suggesting storing job status before start and after completion in config.

I am ok to show status to user with some delay if user is on same page.

I am not sure what is the efficient way of handling this? Can someone suggest me better approach without much performance penaly?

Comment: can you share the link you are referring to? Do you want the live status of your batch job? or the consolidated status once the execution is finished?

Comment: i want the lived status. I am ok to show with some delay upto 5 seconds. i feel polling is pretty inefficient

Comment: have you tried VF remoting to achieve this functionality? Call a controller method through VF remoting in a cyclic manner by putting a wait until you get the status you want.